# PHP Date to strtotime not working

Tags: php, strtotime

Hello everybody I'm new here.

This is working good.

```
$Date       = "05/15/2015";
$StrtoTime  = date(strtotime("$Date"));
echo $StrtoTime;
```

but its not working.

```
$Date       = "15/May/2015";
$StrtoTime  = date(strtotime("$Date"));
echo $StrtoTime;
```

Please help someone for solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Which time format should: `15/May/2015` be? Which [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) understands?

Comment: is it possible to make strtotime from any date format?

Comment: No, then you want probably look into the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) class which gives you the methods to read every custom date format

Answer (score 1):

The valid date formats are listed [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Some examples would be:

```
15-May 2015
May 15, 2015
05/15/2015
15-05-2015
2015-05-15
```

If you truly want to use this non-standard format.  It does happen to work with hyphens instead of slashes so you can fix it with str_replace.

The date() call is unnecessary and used incorrectly.

```
$Date       = "15/May/2015";
$StrtoTime  = strtotime( str_replace("/", "-", "$Date") );
echo $StrtoTime;
```

Comment: is it possible to make strtotime from any date format?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I gave you the list of formats that work with strtotime.

Answer (score 0):

Leave comment if this is the output you are looking for.

Try this maybe the "/" is the error

```
$Date       = "15-May-2015";
$StrtoTime  = date(strtotime("$Date"));
echo $StrtoTime;
```

Output: 1431640800

or

```
$Date       = "15-May-2015";
$StrtoTime  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("$Date"));
echo $StrtoTime;
```

Output: 
2015-05-15

Comment: is it possible to make strtotime from any date format?